# New build options for web ui on Dart 1.0

Tags: dart, dart-webui

I have a Project using still web-ui, and trying to run it on Dart 1.0 but I get an error in this line of code:

```
build(new Options().arguments, ['web/lista_orden_p.html']);
```

What is the new syntax for this?

Answer (score 2):

The Options class has been [depreciated and removed](https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/d/topic/misc/AuTix5oPNjI/discussion) from the dart:io library. the `main()` function now takes a List of strings as the arguments as such:

```dart
 // build.dart

 void main(List<String> args) {
    build(args, ['web/lista_orden_p.html']);
 }
```